# How to calculate the probability of y≈1?

Tags: probability

I have an equation: $$y=\frac{10^{10}x}{10^{10}x+1}$$
X can be any real number between 0 and 1, both inclusive. How do I calculate the probability of y≈1? I’ve a feeling that it’s going to be close to 100%. But how do I show that?

Edit 1: Stipulate that y≈1 to be $1\pm0.0001$.
Edit 2: Remove the constraint that $x$ must be rational.

Comment: I feel it'd be hard to say, unless you formalize what you mean by $y \approx 1$. How wide of an interval is allowed? $1 \pm 0.1$? $1 \pm 10^{100}$?

Comment: I’ll consider 0.9999 to be approximately 1. Does that help?

Comment: Not really because that doesn't establish how close is permissible. Just because $0.9999$ is doesn't mean $0.9$ isn't.

Comment: Let’s stipulate that the interval is 1 \pm 0.0001 then. Is it better?

Comment: You just solve $\frac{x10^{10}}{1 + x10^{10}} \geq 1-\epsilon$ (say, for $\epsilon = 0.0001$).  Can you rearrange that to get $x \geq something$?

Comment: What is the probability distribution among possible values of $x$?

Comment: All the possible values of x are equally likely.

Comment: I got $x\ge9.999\times10^{-7}$

Comment: You specify that X is on the *rational* numbers (not real numbers) in your question. How are you putting a uniform over the *rationals* between 0 and 1? I don't believe that's possible.

Comment: Ah I see. I think I made a mistake. $x$ could be real as well.

Answer (score 1):

Write it as $y=1-\frac 1{10^{10}x+1}$.  If you want the chance that $y \gt c$ you note that the cutoff for $x$ is $$c=1-\frac 1{10^{10}x+1}\\ \frac 1{10^{10}x+1}=1-c\\
{10^{10}x+1}=\frac 1{1-c}\\x=\frac {c}{(1-c)10^{10}}$$
Choose how close you want $y$ to be to $1$, plug the cutoff in to this equation, and you get the minimum $x$ that is acceptable.  Whatever the probability that $x$ is greater than that is the chance $y \approx 1$ to your accuracy.

For $c=0.9999$, we need $x \gt \frac {.9999}{10^6} =.9999\cdot 10^{-6}$  If $x$ is uniform on $(0,1)$ the chance is about $0.999999$

Comment: Note that OP specified that X was *rational*. We can probably presume the intent was the reals in [0,1] but that's not what the question currently asks.

Comment: @Glen_b:  I did note that but because the rationals are dense I don't think it changes much.  My cutoff is rational as well.  Aside from the detail that you can't find a uniform distribution on the rationals my final number is correct.  Now the rational constraint has been removed.

Comment: I think there's a minor mistake. $x=\frac{c}{(1-c)10^{10}}$

Comment: @jshthng:  yes, I dropped a sign.  It doesn't change much.  Thanks.